# ssh no supported authentication methods supported

Tags: centos, ssh

attempting to connect to my new server (using putty 0.70) and am getting the following error from putty: Disconnected: No support authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-with-mic)

here is where I get confused... if I use debug mode on sshd the server lets me in. hopefully all info you may need is below.

server info: CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708
user foder perm: 700
.ssh folder perm: 700
authorized_keys file perm: 600

and I have **triple checked** that I put my key in the file **correctly**

event log from putty

```
Connecting to xx.xxx.xx.xxx port 22
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.70
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
Using SSH protocol version 2
Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
Server also has ssh-ed25519/ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 host keys, but we don't know any of them
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
Pageant has 1 SSH-2 keys
Trying Pageant key #0
Server refused our key
Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
Attempting GSSAPI authentication
GSSAPI authentication request refused
Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

log from `/var/log/secure` while running sshd as normal (no debug)

```
localhost polkitd[661]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2251:676669 (system bus name :1.58 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
localhost sshd[2267]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
localhost sshd[2267]: Server listening on :: port 22.
localhost polkitd[661]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2251:676669 (system bus name :1.58, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
localhost sshd[2268]: error: Received disconnect from xx.xxx.xxx.xx port 63760:14: No supported authentication methods available [preauth]
localhost sshd[2268]: Disconnected from xx.xxx.xxx.xx port 63760 [preauth]
```

and from my server using `/usr/sbin/sshd -d`

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:Rq6yx2xQ7QW4KhnLtxuQP8aq9ZMBEBooF5D80LuxyQk
debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Oek0xG7QM//4lWxH/uBegjKD5/V7WDd+FUdl19Pxq+E
debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:lQj5wuazdOVz0ZHrBraC+z7UqCh740bdYE24uK8tspc
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 13207 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 13207.
debug1: Bind to port 13207 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 13207.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 66.210.152.17 port 52953 on 192.168.1.103 port 13207
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version PuTTY_Release_0.70
debug1: no match: PuTTY_Release_0.70
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: SELinux support enabled [preauth]
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32 [preauth]
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32 [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user david service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: initializing for "david"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "itss-tech14.icnet.net"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: userauth-request for user david service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: userauth_pubkey: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable for RSA SHA256:qiTokvVJjhT1hkBZ2pKqbMH6Ozb986CrlFyFp7OjHkQ [preauth]
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/david/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /home/david/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1 RSA SHA256:qiTokvVJjhT1hkBZ2pKqbMH6Ozb986CrlFyFp7OjHkQ
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Postponed publickey for david from 66.210.152.17 port 52953 ssh2 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user david service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/david/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /home/david/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1 RSA SHA256:qiTokvVJjhT1hkBZ2pKqbMH6Ozb986CrlFyFp7OjHkQ
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: do_pam_account: called
Accepted publickey for david from xx.xxx.xxx.xx port 52953 ssh2: RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: david has been authenticated by privileged process
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
debug1: ssh_gssapi_storecreds: Not a GSSAPI mechanism
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: SELinux support enabled
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
User child is on pid 2295
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 1000/1000
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: ssh_packet_set_postauth: called
debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
debug1: server_init_dispatch
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 256 win 16384 max 16384
debug1: input_session_request
debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: session_open: channel 0
debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request pty-req reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
debug1: Allocating pty.
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: SELinux support enabled
debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/1
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request shell reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req shell
Starting session: shell on pts/1 for xxxx from xx.xxx.xxx.xx port 52953 id 0
debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.
```

Comment: `Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 13207.`... Do you use such a port on purpose? When you run `/usr/sbin/sshd -d` manually, you are running it as root, and not as a regular user, yes?

Comment: Presumably the debug server was started on a nonstandard port so as to not require taking down the regular server which may still be listening on port 22.

Comment: The initial attempt client logs show that PuTTY is attempting the public key: `Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
Pageant has 1 SSH-2 keys
Trying Pageant key #0
Server refused our key`, so for some reason, the server is not accepting what I assume is the same working key from the debug session. Is the non-debug server using a `sshd_config` file that locates the `authorized_keys` location somewhere other than your home directory, or is it perhaps running without capability to access `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` such as an NFS or dynamic mounted filesystem?

Comment: @ ilkkachu: Yes, `/usr/sbin/sshd -d` is being ran as root. Also,  DopeGhoti hit it on the nose with why the different port. @PKapp Not sure... How do I tell for sure which sshd_config file is being used. As for access to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys there should not be any reason why it cannot read it.

Comment: For systemd, start with `systemctl status sshd`, and look at the service definition file (probably `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service`), then find the `EnvironmentFile` listed there, and also look at the `ExecStart` to see the options that it passes in. `$SSHD_OPTS` or `$OPTIONS` may be set in the file listed in `EnvironmentFile`.

For SysV init, look in `/etc/init.d/sshd` or `/etc/init.d/ssh`

Comment: @PKapp: `EnvironmentFile` listed expected `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and `ExecStart` was set to `$OPTIONS`. Neither of the files you pointed out for `SysV init` are there. I have tested the theory of different config files... I stopped the current running sshd service then ran `/usr/sbin/sshd -d` plain and let it load the same config. Still lets me in (but only when running debug).

Comment: If you can, edit the `ssh_config` file and set `LogLevel DEBUG` and restart the daemon. The log messages should provide more clues as to what is happening differently. If you don't see additional (debug level) messages, then the config file is not the one in scope when run as a system daemon, which is my suspicion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ssh_config` file was missing. I determined that something went wrong on the install and purged it from my system. Upon reinstall and configure I was able to connect as one expects